# Azure Web App - adding basic auth through applicationHost.xdt?

Tags: iis-7, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Web App with basic authentication configured for non-PROD environments inside web.config, like below:

```
    <configSections>
            <section name="basicAuth" type="Devbridge.BasicAuthentication.Configuration.BasicAuthenticationConfigurationSection" />
        </configSections>
        <basicAuth allowRedirects="true">
            <credentials>
                <add username="username" password="password"/>
            </credentials>
        </basicAuth>
        <system.webServer>
            <modules>
              <add name="MyBasicAuthenticationModule" type="Devbridge.BasicAuthentication.BasicAuthenticationModule"/>
            </modules>
<!-- the rest of the web.config follows -->
```

Everything works fine, but whenever we do a PROD deployment with changes to web.config, a manual change to the file is required to disable basic auth (as mentioned, we need it on non-prod only).

So I wonder - is there a way to enable basic authentication with applicationHost.xdt file? Since this is a file that is not changed very often, it would make our life easier.

I already checked the IIS Manager extension, but don't see anything that would allow me to make this work. Any hints are appreciated!

**UPDATES - adding my web.config (that I'd like to update with applicationHost.xdt)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)"/>
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$"/>
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, I assumed that you are using [DevBridge Azure Power Tools](https://github.com/devbridge/AzurePowerTools) which supports basic authentication for Windows Azure websites. I followed this project [Devbridge.BasicAuthentication.Test](https://github.com/devbridge/AzurePowerTools/tree/master/Devbridge.BasicAuthentication.Test) to test XDT Transform on my side. I could make it work on my side, you could refer to it.

1.Create a `Release-dev` configuration

Click "Build > Configuration Manager", add a new configuration for the web project.

[image]

2.Add a web configuration file named `Web.Release-dev.config` and configuration the content as follows:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">

  <!--make sure the configSections is the first child element under configuration-->
  <configSections xdt:Transform="InsertBefore(/configuration/*[1])" />
  <configSections xdt:Locator="XPath(/configuration/configSections[last()])">
    <section name="basicAuth" type="Devbridge.BasicAuthentication.Configuration.BasicAuthenticationConfigurationSection" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </configSections>
  <configSections xdt:Transform="RemoveAll" xdt:Locator="Condition(count(*)=0)" />

  <basicAuth allowRedirects="true" xdt:Transform="InsertAfter(/configuration/configSections)">
    <credentials xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
      <add username="test" password="test" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing"/>
    </credentials>
  </basicAuth>

  <system.webServer xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
    <modules xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
      <add name="MyBasicAuthenticationModule" type="Devbridge.BasicAuthentication.BasicAuthenticationModule" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

**Note:** You could refer to [Xdt transform samples](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples). Also, you could follow this official [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx) about the syntax of `xdt:Transform` and `xdt:Locator` attributes that you use in your Web.config transform files.

3.Publish the web project by using the `release-dev` configuration:

[image]

4.Check the deployed web.config file via KUDU:

[image]

Browser the site, you could see the following screenshot:

[image]

**UPDATE**

For a workaround, I assumed that you could exclude web.config file from your git repository. And add the web.config file under "D:\home\site\wwwroot" and `Devbridge.BasicAuthentication.dll` under "D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin" for your DEV and QA environment to enable basic auth as follows:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried deploying mentioned applicationHost.xdt (btw, this is a PHP app, not .NET and we dont use VS, but direct integration with GitHub for deployment). I am getting the following error - "Config section 'system.webServer/modules' already defined. Sections must only appear once per config file.", but I dont have the modules section defined in the web.config (see updated content of the q).

Comment: Ignore my misunderstanding of your scenario. According to your latest updated content, are you meaning that your are trying to add a URL rewrite rule within the `applicationHost.xdt` file to  disable basic auth? If so, there is a xdt transform sample about [Redirect http traffic to https](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples), you could refer to it.

Comment: Also, you could install the site extension called "Redirect HTTP to HTTPS" on Azure Portal under the "DEVELOPMENT TOOLS" > "Extensions" blade of your web app or install [Redirect HTTP to HTTPS](http://www.siteextensions.net/packages/RedirectHttpToHttps/) extension via KUDU.

Comment: Hi Bruce, sorry for misunderstanding :) Situation looks like this - we have a web.config that has quite many rules, with key ones mentioned above (so http->https redirect and for DEV and QA - basic auth), we also have some rewrites, etc. Since web,config is inside SCM, we need to remember to manually remove the basic auth piece every time we deploy changes to PROD (otherwise PROD gets basic auth). What I'd like to achieve is to have applicationHost.xdt that would automatically add basic auth on DEV and QA so that we dont have to hardcode it in the web.config. I hope this time it's clear :)

Comment: I have tried to leverage applicationHost.xdt located in “D:\home\site” on Azure to transfer the basic authentication configurations you configured in Web.config. But I found that it would transfer the configurations within applicationHost.xdt into applicationHost.config (C:\DWASFiles\Sites\\{sitename}\Temp\applicationhost.config) of your web app. However the `Devbridge.BasicAuthentication.dll` would only read configurations from "D:\home\site\wwwroot\web.config", so I assumed that enable basic auth couldn't be achieved by using applicationHost.xdt. For a workaround, please refer to my updates.

Comment: OK, thank you, I think we will proceed with the workaround of moving web.config out of the SCM :)