# Hi How do I change this applicationHost.xdt to use a custom username/password?

Tags: xml, azure, azure-web-app-service, xdt

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <location path="%XDT_SITENAME%" xdt:Locator="Match(path)">
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
        <allowedServerVariables xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
          <add name="RESPONSE_WWW_AUTHENTICATE" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
        </allowedServerVariables>
        <rules xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
          <rule name="BasicAuthentication" stopProcessing="true" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{HTTP_AUTHORIZATION}" pattern="^Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="401" statusReason="Unauthorized" statusDescription="Unauthorized" />
            <serverVariables>
              <set name="RESPONSE_WWW_AUTHENTICATE" value="Basic realm=Project" />
            </serverVariables>
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

I am new to azure. Does anyone know how to add a custom username and password to this config file? the default s user for username and password for password

Comment: you can achieve this by adding basic authentication in your applicationhost.xdt file you can refer this [server fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/901508/configure-basic-authentication-on-azures-app-service) discussion. 

You can also refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41162331/azure-web-app-adding-basic-auth-through-applicationhost-xdt) thread as well

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution for my question:

All I had to do is to run this command in the browser's console with the new username and password:

```
btoa('newuser:newpassword');
```

this will return a base64 encoded string like "dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==", then all you have to do is to change it in the xdt file:

```
<conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_AUTHORIZATION}" pattern="^Basic <YOUR NEWLY GENERATED STRING>" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
</conditions>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to enable Basic Authentication for Azure Web Apps with some settings in the **applicationHost.xdt**. You can load some modules in this file on the start of your Web App.

**Steps:**

- Navigate to your WebApp in the Azure Portal
- In the left menu, search
  for the header **Development Tools** an select **Advanced Tools (Kudu)**
- Use the **Debug Console > CMD tool**, to navigate to the WebApp directory:
  **\home\site**
- Create a file named: **applicationHost.xdt**
- Paste the following:

```html
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
      <location path="%XDT_SITENAME%" xdt:Locator="Match(path)">
        <system.webServer>
          <rewrite xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
            <allowedServerVariables xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
              <add name="RESPONSE_WWW_AUTHENTICATE" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
            </allowedServerVariables>
            <rules xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
              <rule name="BasicAuthentication" stopProcessing="true" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                  <add input="{HTTP_AUTHORIZATION}" pattern="^Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="401" statusReason="Unauthorized" statusDescription="Unauthorized" />
                <serverVariables>
                  <set name="RESPONSE_WWW_AUTHENTICATE" value="Basic realm=Project" />
                </serverVariables>
              </rule>
            </rules>
          </rewrite>
        </system.webServer>
      </location>
    </configuration>
```

- Change the Basic Auth to your liking (default in example is:
  user:password)
- Make sure the web.config rewrite rules don't contain
   as this wil remove the effects from the applicationHost.xdt
  file
- Save the file and Stop and Start your WebApp (a simple Restart
  will not suffice)

**Notes:**

- Not sure if this works on Linux based WebApps..
- You can add this step to you're deployment pipelines by using FTP

**Update:** I've noticed issues with applicationHost.xdt while using it on secondary Web App slots. Only the primary slot seems to work.

For more information you can refer [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/901508/configure-basic-authentication-on-azures-app-service) server fault discussion. You can also refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41162331/azure-web-app-adding-basic-auth-through-applicationhost-xdt) thread(SO thread is using the devBridge tools to enable basic authentication).